# Casting a double result from a divison into an int in Java

Tags: java, casting

I want to use a method that requires an *int*. This *int* is determined by a division potentially solved as a *double*. I need to perform this as neat and short as possible and I am wondering if I can count that the method will take the *double* directly casted as *int* and if this means a single truncation with no roundings.

Do I have to necessarily use *Math* static methods?
Could this give errors for non *int* parameter entries to *subList*?
Could someone provide any guidance about this?

```
List<Integer> b = null;
List<Integer> c = null;
int size = a.size();

b.addAll(a.subList(0, size / 2)); // To hold the first half
c.addAll(a.subList(size / 2, size)); // To hold the second half [and excess]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you trying to find the value of `size / 2`, so that your `a` list is divided into exactly two equally sized sublist without missing any value?

Comment: I don't see how there can be a `double` anywhere in that code. `size / 2` will never return a `double` because you're dividing 2 integers, so the result will be an integer.

Comment: Rohit: I am trying to split the list in two halves doing it flexible enough to let the second half take a potential excess when the size of the initial list is odd, but I don't have deep knowledge about how some things work and if it could produce error in certain scenarios. For example if the List is size 5, we will get two lists of size 2 and 3. If this is autorounding it could not be useful for me requiring explicit cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will take the double casted to integer and will not round it, just disregard everything after the "."

so if the division of 9.8/2 is 4.9 then you'll get 4 for doing

```
int x = 9.8/2;
```

you don't need to use the Math static methods for devision and you won't get errors for the code you gave

to conclude, you can just run your code and see if the result is as you want it.

```
b.addAll(a.subList(0, size / 2));
```

should run without problem

Comment: Thank you. It was clarifying.

Comment: You fellows say that no double is involved in this, so I am deducing that you mean that using the operator "/" if both types are int the result would be auto casted to int? Because I understand the the math result of 5 / 2 is 2.5 which is a number that an int variable can´t hold. Is that right? Can I assume an int truncated result when a division via "/" for two integers is made?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `b.addAll(a.subList(0, (int)(size / 2)));`?

Comment: `size` is an `int`. `size / 2` will automatically be an int. No typecast needed.

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding now.